# Why can't I mount VirtualBox shared folder after Linux kernel update on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, mount

I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Previously, it used Linux kernel version 5.8.0-59 but after the kernel was updated to 5.11.0-25, I found that I am now unable to mount my VirtualBox shared folder due to an error message "No such file or directory".

The command I used to mount the shared folder was (run in my home directory):

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 vboxshared /home/juhis/vboxshared
```

And the VirtualBox configuration had a shared folder in the "Machine Folders" list with name `vboxshared`, which used to work but doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is that something changed in Linux with mounting of devices having relative path. If I run in my home directory the command

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 vboxshared /home/juhis/vboxshared
```

...then it no longer uses `vboxshared` as the device name. Instead, it uses `/home/juhis/vboxshared`. Thus, the VirtualBox settings need to be updated and the device name of the folder which used to be `vboxshared` must be changed to `/home/juhis/vboxshared` (full path).